# Countdown timer where user inputs how long it should run

Tags: javascript, countdown

i am building a countdown timer with javascript and cant seem to find one where the user inputs how long they want the timer to run for.  I've already gotten my timer and linked it to my html file but i need to know how to make it to where the user can input the amount of time they want it to run for.

Comment: What does `2232` mean in the title? Is that a typo?

Comment: it said my title was already taken so i entered some random numbers so i could submit it

Comment: It would be better to use a more distinctive title. Like "Countdown timer where the user inputs the timer length".

Comment: "i am building a ..." and "...cant seem to find one where ..." is an oxymoron.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example:

```js
    var sec = 10;
    $('#btn').on('click', function(){
      
      var timer = setInterval(function(){
        var sec = parseInt($('#timer').val());
        if(sec>0) {
          sec--;
          $('#timer').val(sec);
        } else {
          foo();
          clearInterval(timer);
        }
      }, 1000)
    });

    function foo(){
      alert('Timer ended!');
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input id="timer" value="10" /><button id="btn">Start timer</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Much Simpler One

```js
var timer;

function setTimer(event){

      if(timer) 
      {
         clearInterval(timer)
      }

      var timerValue = document.getElementById("timerstart").value ;
   
      timer = setInterval(function(){
      
        if(timerValue > 0){
        
          document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=timerValue;
          
          timerValue --;
        } else {
          clearInterval(timer)
        }


      },1000);


 }
```

```html
<div>
    <label>Start Timer After(seconds)</label>
    <input type="text" name="timerstart" id="timerstart" />
</div>

<button onclick="setTimer(event)" >Start Timer</button>

<div ><span>Timer : </span><span id="timer"></span></div>
```